# Make my application vague while Show "Spinning Wheel”

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `Windows Forms application` and while some operation is in progress i want to show Spinning Wheel:

http://preloaders.net/en/search/circle

So i created `pictureBox` and while my operation is in progress i want to see that `Wheel` but i want it to seen like in web pages, i want it over my controllers at the middle of the application and if it possible i want the rest of my application become vague.
is it possible ?

Comment: What's different than your previous question [Show "Spinning Wheel” over my Windows Forms application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21990824/719186)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
pictureBox1.BringToFront();
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Another option is [transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309770/c-sharp-transparent-background-for-window-form) and `FormBorderStyle` set to `None`. Show this form with `ShowDialog()` to avoid interaction with main form while it is shown.

NOTE: WinForms is not a Web application. Usually when you have some background process, then you set waiting cursor and disable controls. If you want to display progress, then can use ProgressBar.

Comment: that works fine but if i want meanwhile when i show this circle to disable all my controller so also my circle freeze because it over my controllers, any way to solve it ?

Comment: @user3271698 sorry, I don't understand what *disable all my controller* means? What are controllers and how you want to disable them?

Comment: controllerName.Enable= false;